# Are all algebras groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

It seemed to me that boolean algebra is a group because it is closed (You can't use boolean algebra and get a result that is outside the group) under a logical primitive(?) and order of operands and order of operators don't matter (0+1=1+0). But is it even defined what we mean when we say "an algebra" (abstract algebra, boolean algebra, matrix algebra, Lie algebra...?) and can we know that any "algebra" also is a group?

Comment: When you say a Boolean algebra is a group, which operation are you taking and what are you calling the identity?

Comment: By algebra do you mean the mathematical constructs known as algebras or things that are called "something algebra" like linear algebra or abstract algebra? See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field

Comment: @JohnDouma I think that the elements `{0,1}` with the `+` operation (meaning "or") (or the `NAND´ operation for a functionally complete algebra) then I could google and find articles that say that boolean algebra is a group. If it is, then it is a good example of a group but I never saw it used as an example of a group before, but it seems like a good example to show that a group can define "A mathematic" or "an algebra" so that we know what we mean with the word "algebra".

Comment: What you describe above is a commutative magma; commutativity ($a*b=b*a$) is not a necessary property of groups, and the properties of being associative, having a unit, and having inverses would still need to be verified. It's easy to confirm that a Boolean algebra is not a group under either alternation or conjunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here.

First, Boolean algebras are *not* groups in any immediate sense. A *group* is a set with a binary operation which is associative, has an identity, and has inverses; neither of the main binary operations of a Boolean algebra satisfy this.

That said, we can turn a Boolean algebra into a group with some work: if $(B; \wedge, \vee, \neg)$ is a Boolean algebra, then $(B; XOR)$ is a group - "exclusive or" is associative and has an identity ($\bot$) and inverses (each element is its own inverse).

---

I think what you ultimately want is **universal algebra**.

An *algebra* is just a set $X$ with a family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ on (finite Cartesian powers of) $X$. We also say $(X, \mathcal{F})$ is a *$\Sigma$-algebra*, where $\Sigma$ is a set of function symbols, if there's a bijection ("interpretation") between $\Sigma$ and $\mathcal{F}$ which preserves arity (an $n$-ary function symbol gets mapped to an $n$-ary function).

Examples:

- A **group** is a $(*, ^{-1}, e)$-algebra, where $*$ is a binary function symbol, $^{-1}$ is a unary function symbol, and $e$ is a zero-ary function symbol (= constant symbol).
- A **Boolean algebra** is a $(\wedge, \vee, \neg, \top, \bot)$-algebra, where $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are binary function symbols, $\neg$ is a unary function symbol, and $\top$ and $\bot$ are zero-ary function symbols (= constant symbols).

(Of course, that's not *all* a group or Boolean algebra is - we also demand that they satisfy some *equations* in the relevant language.)

Now, from any set of function symbols, we can form the set of *polynomials* over that set: basically, all the functions built up from those function symbols and variable symbols. E.g. in the language of Boolean algebras, the following are polynomials:

- $y\mapsto y\wedge y$,
- $x, y\mapsto x\vee (x\wedge y)$
- $x, y\mapsto (x\vee y)\wedge (\neg x\vee \neg y)$ (**this one is "XOR"**).

What we've observed above is that there are terms in the language of Boolean algebras, which turn the set into a group. In a particularly nice sense, every Boolean algebra "interprets" a group (there is a very wide class of notions of "interpret" here).

Universal algebra, among other things, studies the structural properties of algebras in terms of their polynomials. I think this would be interesting to you.

---

EDIT: You should note that "algebra" often refers to something much more specific - the "ring version" of a vector space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field). But I don't think that's what you're looking for here.

Comment: See also http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/willard-ua.pdf. High level, but quite good.

Comment: Thank you for a very good answer. IIUC any group is an algebra but not all groups are algebras. Is boolean algebra a field? It seems the definition is somewhat similar to a field (for instance the field "_ℂ_" is the complex set with functions) or do we know that boolean algebra is not a field?

Comment: @Programmer400 First of all, *how do you propose to view a Boolean algebra as a field*? You need to tell me which operation in the Boolean algebra you want to be "$+$," etc. If you do that the obvious way - $\vee$ is $+$ and $\wedge$ is $\times$ - then this will **not** work, since e.g. $\vee$ does not have inverses. There is, however, a way to view a Boolean algebra as a *ring* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring), which extends the interpretation of Boolean algebras as groups described in my answer; this ring, however, is *not* always a field.

Comment: Look at the equations which need to hold for something to be a group/ring/field/Boolean algebra/etc. - they are as much, if not more, a part of the definition of that type of object as the language. As it happens, Boolean algebras and fields satisfy very different-looking equations . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I think that OP is using "Boolean algebra" to mean *the* (2-element) Boolean algebra, not the more general structure.

Comment: I can recognize boolean algebra but I can't formally define it. The similarity I was thinking of was of a set with operands and operators similarly to how you "define" the complex plan with the symbol `ℂ` something that looked like: `ℂ: {x,y ....  ´ and I was wondering if I can define a mathematical system using mathematics rather than just use the system, since I am only a user of Boolean algebra, I don't know what it is.

Comment: My background is a course in discrete math (where the Norman Biggs book was used) and a course in logic where Graeme Forbes Symbolic Logic was used. I want to learn more lika that but I don't know exactly what I'm looking for. I also took all other undergraduate math courses and passed them (analysis and numerical methods) but my interests were discrete mathematics and symbolic logic with exactly those books. If I enjoyed those 2 books, can you recommend me more reading? I'm currently reading Peter Cameron's combinatorics book and David Wunsch's complex analysis to teach myself some more.

Comment: @Programmer400 I don't really understand your more recent comment - can you try to clarify? Re: your second comment, I very strongly recommend Boolos/Burgess/Jeffrey's book "Computability and Logic" (whatever edition it currently is).